# Error #2048: Security sandbox violation

Tags: sockets, actionscript, flash-cs6

I've read just about every article available on the Internet regarding "Error #2048" and "Security sandbox violation".  I've tried every solution offered, but the problem still persists.

The detailed version of my efforts can be found at the following link:
http://forums.adobe.com/message/4668901#4668901

To summarize, I'm using Flash Professional CS6 with AS3 trying to establish a binary socket connection to a server I developed in C#.  I discovered at one point I needed to have a policy server to serve up the requested crossdomain.xml on port 843, but despite following every bread crumb I'm still being haunted by "Error #2048: Security sandbox violation".

I ran across a few references that mentioned placing the SWF on a remote server, so I tried this by firing up a VirtualBox session running Server 2012 RC and had the same results--despite browsing the HTML page from the Guest OS.

I've noticed documentation on Adobe is severely outdated, so I don't know if maybe I just missed the announcement that they're pulling socket support for developing your own server or if this is their way to force you into purchasing their media servers.

Perhaps there is another way to go about this, but what I'm looking to accomplish is being able to communicate with a Flash Application to a back-end Server with real-time data.  I'm not looking to stream video or music, just text data packets.  The back-end Server would be developed using C#.

Any feedback or suggestions appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution required 3 changes.  The first had to do with how the "AddressFamily" was being identified.  The next item was changing the IPAddress for the IPEndPoint from a source of an AddressList to "IPAddress.Any".  The last item was somewhat odd, as the Server didn't seem to pick up any new connections until I defined the Listener with MaxConnections.

See my Adobe Forum [message](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4668901#4668901) for more details.